# Microsoft Book Pages

Tags: book-length

I use Microsoft Word to write stories then I send it to a publisher. But, I want to know how many pages would the book version would be because I want to make long stories and/or books.

Answer (score 2):

Set the page size, margins, and font in MS Word to match what the book will be when it is printed. Then see how many pages it takes. This will only be as exact as the information you have available, but it should get you in the ballpark.